# Как при помощи groovy сделать вывод чисел в переменную по порядку, от 1 до 100?

Tags: jmeter, groovy

К примеру, есть функция `${__Random(1,100,parName)}`
Которая выводит рандомное число и сохраняет его в переменную.
Можно ли реализовать подобное через `${__groovy(,)}` , чтобы выводились числа по порядку, от 1 до 100?
Буду очень благодарен за источник, где можно почитать, как перебирать числа и выводить их по очереди для параметризации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это-то можно, только я не вижу для валидных сценариев использования.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы хотите увеличивающееся значение с каждым циклом - JMeter дает это "из коробки", например:

1. `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` - для [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` - для [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)
3. `${__jm__While Controller__idx}` - для [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)
4. Еще есть [функция __counter() и конфигурационный элемент Counter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-counter) если вдруг вышеупомянутых не хватает

Comment: Upto перебирает все числа, а для параметризации нужно к примеру, чтобы выводил 1 в переменную. Затем 2. Затем 3. И так далее.

Comment: "Затем" это при каких обстоятельствах?

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл описать. При параметризации внутри jdbc реквеста. В sql запрос. Чтобы при каждой итерации число обновлялось начиная с 1 и выше, хоть до бесконечности, пока длится тест

Comment: Если вы хотите именно __groovy() - `${__groovy(vars.getIteration(),parName)}`, где **vars** это экземпляр класса [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html). Популярные классы которые можно использовать описаны в статье [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes). Но оптимальнее просто взять переменную от того контроллера, который создает эту итерацию как описано  в ответе.

Comment: спасибо, реально помогаете. Почитаю